# how to add a field to User.groups.through in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add my field to the table user_user_group.
I can add a field to table groups but I can not add a field to the many-to-many group field in the user model. I use a monkey solution for add field to groups model but it does not work for many-to-many group field in the user model.

this code work:

```
Group.add_to_class('type', models.IntegerField(choices=RoleType.choices, default=RoleType.ADMIN))
```

this code does not work:

```
User.groups.through.add_to_class('organization', models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True))
```

are you have any solution?

solve this solution or tell me other solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create my User model that defines its relationship with Group with a ManyToManyField using the through parameter to specify my custom table.
I also wouldn’t try to add fields directly to the Group table.

For example I need added organization to UserGroups:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
        through="UserGroups"
    )


 class UserGroups(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```